# Hibernate 6.2.7.FINAL, 6.2.9.FINAL ignoring discriminator column on retreival

Tags: hibernate-6.x

Hibernate 6.2.7.FINAL,  6.2.9.FINAL ignores the discriminator column on retreival.

I created a hibernate project ... to verify this.. it works perfectly with hibernate 5, but fails with 6.

Hibernate 5 query

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        zoo_.id as id1_4_0_,
        zoo_.currentStatus as currents2_4_0_,
        zoo_.lrn as lrn3_4_0_,
        zoo_.ZOO_DETAILS_ID as referenc4_4_0_,
        zoodetails_.id as id1_3_1_,
        zoodetails_.CURRENT_ZOO_ID as current_4_3_1_,
        tiger_.id as id2_1_2_,
        tiger_.sequenceNumber as sequence3_1_2_,
        tiger_.totalGrossMass as totalgro4_1_2_,
        tiger_.ZOO_ID as ZOO_id5_1_2_ 
    from
        ZOO zoo_ 
    left outer join
        ZOO_DETAILS zoodetails_ 
            on zoo_.ZOO_DETAILS_ID=zoodetails_.id 
    left outer join
        TIGER tiger_ 
            on zoo_.id=tiger_.ZOO_ID 
            and tiger_.ANIMAL_TYPE='Tiger' 
    where
        zoo_.id=?
```

Hibernate 6 query

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        t1_0.id,
        t1_0.currentStatus,
        t1_0.lrn,
        m1_0.id,
        m1_0.sequenceNumber,
        m1_0.totalGrossMass,
        r1_0.id,
        r1_0.CURRENT_ZOO_ID,
    from
        ZOO t1_0 
    left join
        TIGER m1_0 
            on t1_0.id=m1_0.ZOO_ID 
    left join
        ZOO_DETAILS r1_0 
            on r1_0.id=t1_0.ZOO_DETAILS_ID 
    where
        t1_0.id=?
```

Works with hibernate 5, not sure what changed in 6